# Subcategory of a category consisting of collection of objects

Tags: category-theory

The following is Exercise 3.7 from Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter Zero* (available [here](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf)):

> A subcategory $C'$ of a category $C$ consists of a collection of objects of $C$, with morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_{C'} (A,B) \subseteq \operatorname{Hom}_C (A,B)$ for all objects $A, B$ in $\operatorname{Obj}(C')$, such that identities and compositions in $C$ make $C'$ into a category. A subcategory $C'$ is full if $\operatorname{Hom}_{C'} (A,B) = \operatorname{Hom}_C (A,B)$ for all $A,B$ in $\operatorname{Obj}(C')$. Construct a category of infinite sets and explain how it may be viewed as a full subcategory of set.

Comment: Yes, that works well. What have you tried? There is almost nothing to do.

Comment: That is the question. I am confused because the question does almost all the work

Comment: On second thoufgt, you are right. One would actually *define* the category of infinite set as the full subcategory of **Set** whose objects are the infinite sets ... Hm, just write that down, i.e. "Let $Obj(C')$ be ... and for infinite sets $A,B$ let $\operatorname{Hom}_{C'}(A,B)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf {Set}}(A,B)$ ..."

Comment: Let $Obj(C')$ be what?

Comment: Let $Obj(C')$ be the class of infinite sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $C$ is a category and $S \subseteq \mathrm{ob}(C)$ is a subclass of its objects, there is a unique full subcategory $C' \subseteq C$ with $\mathrm{ob}(C')=S$. This is trivial - nothing has to be proven. In the "exercise", $C$ is the category of sets, and $S$ is the class of all infinite sets. We get the category of infinite sets with maps betweem them.

Comment: Done? Is that all to the exercise